# Angular 12 (node:3224) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid mapping:

Tags: angular, typescript, internationalization, angular-translate

on my Angular projet, when I try to generate the translate file with the command `ng extract-i18n --output-path src/translate`, I have this error message :

```
\ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...(node:3224) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid mapping: {"generated":{"line":1
21955,"column":0},"source":"webpack://./node_modules/packages/reactive-form-validators/decorators/alpha.decorator.ts","original":{"line":7,"column":-16},
"name":null}
    at SourceMapGenerator_validateMapping [as _validateMapping] (C:\Users\user\Documents\workspace xxx\pjtv0-front-end\node_modules\webpack\node_modul
es\source-map\lib\source-map-generator.js:298:13)
    at SourceMapGenerator_addMapping [as addMapping] (C:\Users\user\Documents\workspace xxx\pjtv0-front-end\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\source-m
ap\lib\source-map-generator.js:110:12)
    at C:\Users\user\Documents\workspace xxx\pjtv0-front-end\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-node.js:351:13
    at SourceNode_walk [as walk] (C:\Users\user\Documents\workspace xxx\pjtv0-front-end\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-node.j
s:230:9)
    at SourceNode_walk [as walk] (C:\Users\user\Documents\workspace xxx\pjtv0-front-end\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-node.j
s:226:13)
    at SourceNode_walk [as walk] (C:\Users\user\Documents\workspace xxx\pjtv0-front-end\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-node.j
s:226:13)
    at SourceNode_walk [as walk] (C:\Users\user\Documents\workspace xxx\pjtv0-front-end\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-node.j
s:226:13)
    at SourceNode_walk [as walk] (C:\Users\user\Documents\workspace xxx\pjtv0-front-end\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-node.j
s:226:13)
    at SourceNode_walk [as walk] (C:\Users\user\Documents\workspace xxx\pjtv0-front-end\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-node.j
s:226:13)
    at SourceNode_toStringWithSourceMap [as toStringWithSourceMap] (C:\Users\user\Documents\workspace xxx\pjtv0-front-end\node_modules\webpack\node_mo
dules\source-map\lib\source-node.js:342:8)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:3224) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a
 catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI fl
ag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3224) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will termin
ate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
| Generating browser application bundles (phase: sealing)...
```

I have already updated angular modules to the latest version, a npm fix doesn't resolve the problem. Have you an ideas ?

Comment: It would be very helpful if we could see the code in the area that the error message has highlighted. That way it is possible for people to assist you.

Comment: The code in is in library prent on github : https://github.com/webpack/webpack.

Comment: Links can go stale, so in the future others can't benefit from answer to the same type of issue. Links take additional work for people who might be kind enough to try to help you. Please not how much response your question has received, so far. Please, help people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem,
I remove the  webpack package, he was entered in conflict with webpack present in angular packages.